# In C++/cli, should a ref class have a destructor(=Dispose) to manage native memory?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, idisposable

I've seen the following pattern in our code base:

```
public ref class FooWrapper {
public:
    FooWrapper(); // does m_p(new NativeFoo)
    ~FooWrapper(); // calls !FooWrapper(), does nothing else (doesn't close any non-memory resource)

    // ... DoStuff() ...

protected:
    !FooWrapper(); // does delete m_mp;

private:
    NativeFoo* m_mp;
    // possibly more (managed/native) members 
};
```

What this achieves is that:

- The native pointer will be freed when the managed object is collected by the GC - through the Finalizer (`!FooWrapper()`)
- If you `Dispose()` of the object (e.g. `using`), the native memory will be reclaimed immediately, not waiting for garbage collection of the containing object.

After thinking about this for a while, I think this is actually neither needed nor helpful, as we don't actually *need* the IDisposable interface on this type.

Would it be safe and OK to have the native pointer only be freed on Finalization and do away with the "destructor"?

Would the destructor (`~FooWrapper()`) be ever (implicitly) needed in in the C++/CLI code, or can I create a `ref class` *only* with `gcnew` anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah yes. A destructor *is* optional, just like [Hans says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23023386/321013).

However, MS implemented a very (un?)helpful Level 1 warning:

> **C4461 - ['type' : this class has a finalizer 'finalizer' but no destructor
>   'dtor'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235250.aspx)**
>
> The presence of a finalizer in a type implies resources to delete.
>   Unless a finalizer is explicitly called from the type's destructor,
>   the common language runtime determines when to run the finalizer,
>   after your object goes out of scope.

So for my case I have the choice of either:

- Adding a dtor==IDisposable that essentially doesn't do anything helpful beyond cleaning up memory (calling the finalizer) deterministically iff the object is used in a using statement (or `IDisposable` is otherwise triggered -- `foreach`, etc.)
- Removing the warning with a pragma.
- <strike>Implement the dtor, but male it a noop, which would allow the object to be still used after it has been disposed (noop dispose).</strike> It's not actually possible to have the dtor as noop, because [*if you have a dtor, and it's called, your finalizer will automatically be suppressed.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177197%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (see also [`GC::SuppressFinalize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2))

Comment: Well, don't male the noop, #pragma warning was made for this.

Comment: @MArtin - Why the need for a Finalizer in the first place in that case?

Comment: @DavidV.Corbin - the finalizer is required to delete the native memory. This is the job of the finalizer, not the dtoe in C++/CLI

Comment: @MartinBa - NO not *required*... A simple method named "GoAwayYouNative()" could do it... The question is about reliability, and what happens *if* (when?) one forgets to do the right thing.

Comment: @DavidV.Corbin - well technically you can do anything or nothing in the finalizer. You can also just leak the memory. Personally I think any class that manages native resources and does not make sure all are cleaned up in the finalizer (latest point, earlier GoAwayNative() is optional) is buggy. Which is, as I think you say, about reliability==correctness.

Comment: @MartinBa - That is why I highlighted "required".... for example, it is not "required" that I breath, but there will certainly be consequences if I do not.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, a destructor is optional.  Unfortunately there's a lot of cargo cult surrounding it, but C++/CLI makes it very easy to hide and avoids anybody from getting nervous.  Omitting is quite reasonable if the native object being wrapped only requires a small amount of memory and no handles.  Up to you to define "small", it can be quite large if your C++/CLI wrapper isn't small or is used in the kind of program where you can expect a healthy garbage collections rate.  Strings help a lot, they chew through gen#0 heap quickly.

Happens a lot already, [Runtime Callable Wrappers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) don't have a destructor.  Which is the other strong motivation to not add it, if it is hard to call then adding it just causes pain and suffering and a lot of support calls.  Compare to the Thread class: a megabyte of VM and 5 operating system handles, but no destructor.  Exceedingly difficult to call the destructor of course.  Nobody notices either, they don't create threads that often.  C++/CLI wrappers often fit that mold.

If it is very easy to call, very short lifetime and just a *using* statement in C# in a method body then always add it.

This way, that way, only you can make the call.

Comment: Does a thread occupy a meg of VM when it isn't running?  If a thread is running, its execution context must absolutely positively be kept in VM even if someone tries to `Dispose` it, and if it either hasn't launched or has terminated, I don't think it holds anything near a meg of VM.  I think the reason threads don't implement `IDisposable` is that disposing a running thread would be semantically awkward, and the resources used by non-running threads are not particularly scarce.  In such cases, it may be worthwhile for code to ensure that resources don't get cleaned up until any and all...

Comment: ...outside references to them are well and truly gone (don't put the finalizer on a publicly-accessible object, but only on a privately-held one to which the public object holds a reference; ensure that a long weak reference to the public object is kept somewhere that will always have a strong reference to it, and have the private object's finalizer check that the long weak reference has been invalidated (if it hasn't, re-register for finalization).  Not exactly convenient, but if one doesn't go to such lengths and a reference to one's object is stored in an outside object...

Comment: ...that is abandoned but resurrects itself, an object's finalizer could get run while live references to the object are in use.  The aforementioned pattern would ensure that the cleanup code can't run until after the GC hasn't merely noticed a lack of references to the publicly-exposed, but has actually irretrievably annihilated it.

Comment: C++/CLI destructor syntax is an implementation of "void Dispose()" ... read the IDisposable interface documentation. It should be implemented for one and only one very specific purpose....the class owns an unmanaged object. ALL other use cases have better solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of defining a destructor (aka Dispose pattern) is to allow for deterministic finalisation.  It's technically optional but there's never any reason to not include one if you have some unmanaged members or some managed members that are also disposable.

At the end of the day, if you don't think it's worthwhile to destroy these deterministically, then you can simply never call it (via stack semantics or `delete` from C++, or `using` or `Dispose()` from C# and other languages).

Whether it's worthwhile or not will depend on what is contained in the object and how often you create instances.  (Don't forget the latter: it's perfectly valid for the GC to **never** delete anything during the lifetime of your app, and even small allocations will add up over time.  And remember that it's also valid for the finaliser to never be called.)

Generally speaking, any of the below should be disposable (and actually disposed):

- holding large chunks of memory
- holding limited resources (such as OS handles)
- holding processing resources (such as threads)
- holding shared resources (such as files or locks)
- native types using the RAII pattern
- native types that have side effects when destroyed (eg. smart ptrs, some fluent-style objects)
- objects created very frequently

Comment: Read the start of the documentation:"Provides a mechanism for releasing unmanaged resources." -- unmanaged, unmanaged unmanaged.... anything else is a mis-use [including the places the .NET teams have violated this]. For all other use-cases there are alternative soutions.

Comment: No, you're thinking of a finalizer, which is a different method.